# Show marker symbol at a timestamp on datetime axis in highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am looking to show marker symbol against a timestamp on datetime x axis, does highcharts have support for this?

I am trying to mark symbol on chart load as below but that is not working as expected as we need to show the point against a timestamp. This is what I have so far.

```
chart: {
  type: 'column',
  marginTop: 50,
  height: '220px',
  animation: false,
  events: {
    load() {
      const xAxis = this.xAxis[0],
        yAxis = this.yAxis[0],
        r = 5,
        y = yAxis.toPixels(0),
        x = xAxis.toPixels(10);
        console.log(xAxis);
        console.log(yAxis);

      this.renderer.text('', x, y + r, 'circle')
        .css({
          transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)'
        }).add().toFront();

      this.renderer.circle(x, y, r).attr({
        fill: '#01a982',
      }).add().toFront();
    }
  }
}
```

I am looking for something like this
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the API says, you need to pass the *value in terms of axis units*. In the case of `datetime` axis, it is a `timestamp`.

**API Reference:**
https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#toPixels

```
events: {
  load() {
    const xAxis = this.xAxis[0],
      yAxis = this.yAxis[0],
      r = 5,
      y = yAxis.toPixels(0),
      x = xAxis.toPixels(this.series[0].data[0].x);

    this.renderer.circle(x, y, r).attr({
      fill: '#01a982',
    }).add().toFront();
  }
}
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/5geqbs8m/

Comment: super cool! thanks for this.series[0].data[0].x , is there a way we can clear and redraw element when we zoom in and out?

Comment: destroy helped me to clear the svg element. Thanks for the great help @magdalena

Comment: Glad to hear you figured it out and happy I could help!